# Google App indexing for games

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-app-indexing

I have just games in my Google dev account and I see lot of buzz about Google's App Indexing latest update and new features, so I want to ask you guys are **app indexing works for Android games?** Because I don't understand exactly how it's works, but if it's work for games, there is one more piece in this puzzle game about ASO and driving installs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's App Indexing works for any apps including games. **To enable App Indexing**:

1. Enable App Indexing in your mobile app.
2. Prepare the website content that corresponds to your app.
3. Verify your setup.
   After you complete these steps, you’ll be able to see how your links are performing in Google Search results by extracting the referrer information that Google attaches to your links. You can also check for errors in your Android app using Search Console.

**Technical requirements for Google's App Indexing of Android apps**:

1. Developed on apps with a minsdkVersion no higher than 17.
2. Available on searches using the Google app version 2.8+, and Chrome for Android 4.1+.
3. Available for signed-in users.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing